# Query Enum type on Prisma

Tags: typescript, postgresql, enums, prisma

I am trying to run a query on a simple prisma entity `User`.
Model:

```
model User {
  id           Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String?
  email        String           @unique
  role         Role             @default(USER)
}
```

Entity `User` includes a prop called `Role` with a type of enum.
`Role` enum:

```
enum Role {
  USER
  ADMIN
}
```

Except doing it in raw SQL query, how is this possible to do with Prisma where API:

```
const whereNameIs = await prisma.user.findMany({
  name: 'Rich',
  role: ?
})
```

Any custom `enum` type written in TS or conversion won't match. Is there any workaround in typescript for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prisma library gives named export of any enum types you have defined in the schema file:

```
import { Role } from '@prisma/client'

app.get('users', async (req, res) => {
  const users = await prisma.user.findMany({
    name: 'Rich',
    role: Role.ADMIN
  });
});
```

if you receive the value dynamically, say through a query string, then it would be as follows:

```
const { role } = req.query;

const users = await prisma.user.findMany({
  name: 'Rich',
  role: Role[role as keyof typeof Role]
});
```